# show mysql database values by selecting the date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

if you visit here http://www.joomusic.info/joosilver.php you can understand my concept. i have set all script and calender and i make table in the mysql database table name is Firstname and there are 2 columns in this table 1, Drawtime and 2, winningnumbers. and i have made connect.php file for connected the databse

this is half script because i dont no how i make it full

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<!--<strong><div align="right" id="timeval" style="color:#FF6600; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">--:--:--</div></strong>--> 
    <table width="420" border="1" >
    <form name="showdraw" action="ooo.php" method="post">
    <tr  bgcolor="#FF6600">
            <td><script> DateInput('cdate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); </script></td>
            <td> <input type="submit" value ="Show"> <input type="hidden" value="Show" name="action"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="#FF6600">
        <td><h2>Draw Time</h2></td>
        <td><h2>Wining Number</h2></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
<?php
include('connect.php');
```

now after this include('connect.php); which php script i add in this page then my script work like this http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php

Comment: Your second link isn't working for me.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: ok i set also 2nd link @Quixrick

Comment: Okay, I see it now.  What's the difference between the two?  And what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Chitowns24 my question is this that i want to make same like this box which are you see in this link

Comment: @Quixrick can you correct script if you understand

Comment: So you want to know how to query the database and retrieve the data to display into a table?

Comment: yes i want @Quixrick i hope you see this link and understand i want same this [link]http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php

Comment: @user3412535 How does Drawtime appear in your DB?

Comment: database name is Win and Draw time appear like this (drawtime)

Comment: Okay, well I'll assume that Drawtime appears like this `2014-03-12 16:15:00`.  Is that alright?

Comment: @Quixrick they update the value every 30 mint ... if i have this script then i update every hour only..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well there's actually a lot to do to get it to work, but I'm going to concentrate on getting the results from the database.  Basically, just pull the date value from the post string (I do not know what you named it, so I called it `date`).  Then, pass that to your database and loop through the results.  Finally format the date to just show the hours and minutes and then stick it into a table.

```
// GET THE DATE FROM THE FORM
// I DON'T KNOW WHAT THE NAME OF YOUR DATE FIELD IS, BUT CHANGE IT IN $_POST['FIELD NAME']
$draw_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));


// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE - THIS SHOULD BE SET ALREADY IN YOUR connect.php
$link = mysqli_connect('DATABASE HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');


// BUILD OUT THE QUERY TO GET ALL RECORDS WITH THE SAME DRAW DATE AND ORDER THEM BY TIME
$query = "SELECT Drawtime, winningnumbers FROM Firstname WHERE Drawtime = '".$draw_date."' ORDER BY Drawtime";


// EXECUTE THE QUERY
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Cannot Get Winning Numbers");


// START PRINTING OUT THE TABLE
print "
        <table>";


// LOOP THROUGH EACH OF THE RESULTS FROM THE DATABASE AND PRINT THEM OUT
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // FORMAT THE DATE SO IT IS ONLY SHOWING THE TIME
    print "
        <tr>
          <td>".date("H:i", strtotime($row['Drawtime']))."</td>
          <td>".$row['winningnumbers']."</td>
        </tr>";

}

// CLOSE UP YOUR TABLE
print "
        </table>";
```

Comment: you said that there's actually a lot to do to get it to work, what do you mean ?

Comment: can you make it for me please its can't work like this http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php

Comment: can you give me your email i will send the calender script will you make this box ... please....!!!

Comment: No, sorry.  I can't make it for you.  I've answered the question that you asked, but I do not have the resources (time) to build out the whole thing for you.  I don't mean to be rude, but trying to find out what you wanted and put together code to answer your question has taken me well over an hour already.  Sorry about that.

Comment: :( i want like this i again and again repeat the site in this site you see box i want only this box when i select any date then value show from the database by selecting date

Comment: Hire someone to do it at this point, this isn't a place that does work for you. It helps you understand problems and helps you find answers